# Meteor subscribe onReady() and observe() added double counted

Tags: meteor

I want to wait for all data to be downloaded from the subscription and then create map markers for them all at once at the beginning. To do this, I have a session variable set to false. Then when onReady calls, I initialize all the markers. Then I set the session variable true indicating that the first delivery is in and initialized. In my observe callback, I check the session variable and so long as its false, I dont add any markers. Then, if its true, I will add markers -- assuming non of these markers are already initialized. Sometimes, however, I get a double-count and create twice as many markers.

I guess a good first question to ask is what the relationship is between onReady and observe added? Its not terribly clear in the docs. Is this even the correct way of doing things -- creating a session variable to suppress the observe added function until onReady is done? I dont think so. Also note that the double count doesnt happen every time so its a timing thing... kind of annoying.

Thanks

Comment: Is your `.observe` query somewhere where it can be reactively rerun? In a `Deps.autorun`, `Template` helper, or does it have reactive params in its `.find()` query?

Comment: its in a template rendered function

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the behavior with `observe()`. When you run observe initially it will have an initial query that will match everything and run into `added`.

It is also present when `onReady` hasn't yet fired but the collections are empty at that point so the initial ones aren't visible. This is mentioned in the docs

> Before observe returns, added (or addedAt) will be called zero or more times to deliver the initial results of the query.

I'm not sure entirely how to avoid the initial items. I have done something like this in the past:

```
var QueryHandle = Collection.find().observe({
    added: function() {
        if(!QueryHandle) return false;
    });
```

I know this works on the server but I'm not certain if it does on the client.

Another solution would be to run the handle before `onReady` is called and only stop returning if the subscription is complete: i.e

```
Meteor.subscribe("collection", function() {
   subscribed = true;
});

var QueryHandle = Collection.find().observe({
    added: function() {
        if(!subscribed) return false;
    } 
);
```

Be careful not to run this in a `Deps.autorun` because then it would be run again if the `.find()` query params are reactive.

This might happen sometimes depending on how fast the server response. If you use `Session` it becomes a reactive hash so if it happens fast enough that subscribed returns true. Try using an ordinary variable instead.

If its not helpful there might be an alternative way to avoid the initial ones and a deeper level but it might take a dig into the `livedata` package.

Comment: Thats basically the setup I have except with a session variable. I see what youre saying though -- I try with an ordinary variable and see how that works. thanks